# Javascript Slider and Close Window Codes Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, new-window

I am building a website that uses a Javascript slider.  When I tried the page, it worked well.  I added another Javascript code that made the window close when I clicked the checkout button.  After adding that code, the slider didn't work anymore.

All of this code is on a new window that pops up when people click from the index page.  The new window opens, people can view images in the slider, and then click a button to close the page automatically and return to the index.

Does anyone have any idea why both codes won't work?  Thanks for any help.

**Initial Header Scripts**

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

**Slider Code + New Window Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: "thumbnails"
  });
});
    </script>


  <script language="Javascript"> 
flag = 1; 
function newwin() { 
if (flag==1) { 
open("http://item2.gmarket.co.kr/Item/detailview/Item.aspx?goodscode=375790954", "_blank"); 
self.close(); 
} 
} 
</script>
```

**The button code for returning to the index**

```
<a href='#' onclick="newwin();""><img src="images/purchase.png" width="90" height="30" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick="newwin();""`

see the extra `"` here.That might resolved your problem..

Comment: @user2717222  No, issues,Please mark it as answer,If you found helpful :)